# Не работает вычисление в консоли

Tags: c++

Не знаю почему, но у меня не работает вычисление в консоли, на этом участке кода. Что-бы я туда не вводил - постоянно 0. Что это может быть?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(0, "");
    double x;
    double k;
    cout << "Введите x: ";
    cin >> x;
    k = (sin(x) != 0) ? (sin(x))/(x) : abs(1) - (abs(x))^4;
    cout << "K = " << k << endl;
}
```

Comment: `(abs(x))^4` - это должно означать возведение в четвертую степень?

Comment: да, должно означать 4 степень

Comment: означать должно... но не означает

Comment: И что надо делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k = (sin(x) != 0) ? sin(x) / x : (1 - pow(x, 4));
```

Comment: А, ну да, я туплю утром, при чем жестко. Спасибо. Обязательно отмечу Ваш ответ =)